# How to write a unit test for thread unsafe collection

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, tdd, thread-safety

I'm writing a doubly-linked list using TDD approach. This collection type is not thread safe. In order to implement the ICollection interface my list class must have several public properties (including IsSynchronized and SyncRoot which are used to provide a thread-safe way for collection using).
The code of these two properties is pretty simple:

```
public bool IsSynchronized { get { return false; } }

private readonly object _syncRoot = new object();
public object SyncRoot { get { return _syncRoot; } }
```

The question is how to write a correct unit test for it. This test should check the right usage and incorrect usage either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> my list class must have several public properties (including IsSynchronized and SyncRoot

It doesn't.  This dates back to .NET version 1 and is widely considered a giant mistake.  It created a false sense of thread-safety that got a lot of programmers in deep trouble.  Such a class wasn't actually thread-safe in all cases, iterating for one wasn't.  It was completely dropped in the .NET 2.0 generic collection classes.  And you should not implement ICollection, a modern collection class should be generic and implement `ICollection<T>`.  That unfortunately still requires implementing IEnumerable, a legacy we'll probably never get rid of.  You implement it with an explicit implementation, such methods are not public.

A secondary consideration is whether implementing ICollection<> is a good idea.  A linked list makes a member like Count expensive, it is O(n) by nature.  You need to track the number of elements in the list separately to make it O(1).  The .NET LinkedList<> class, also a doubly linked-list collection class, does do this.

Comment: I don't think implementing `ICollection<T>` actually does require implementing `ICollection`; the generic version only inherits from `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thanks @Dan, you're quite correct.  Tripped up by LinkedList<> which implements it.  Updated.

Comment: >  It created a false sense of thread-safety that got a lot of programmers in deep trouble.

So is there any common way (pattern) to make a collection thread-safe or not?



> The .NET LinkedList<> class, also a doubly linked-list collection class, does do this.
Yes, I know it. I have just tried to implement own collection of that kind with some additional features.

Comment: offtop. Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow and I don't know how to apply markup to comment yet. Sorry for my poor English also.

Comment: There are thread-safe concurrent collections in .net 4, but those usually have an api specifically designed for thread-safe atomic operations. But in many scenarios you don't want to make the collection itself threadsafe, but the class that's build on top of it.

Comment: @key: another doozy is the Queue class: if (q.Count > 0) obj = q.Dequeue().  That's fundamentally thread-unsafe, no way for the Queue class to make it safe.  Other than by completely redesigning the class  (TryDequeue for example).  There is no common way, it is typically up to the client code to use the class in a thread-safe manner.  That's what sucks about threading, the programmer least likely to know enough about your class has to do the hardest job.

Comment: Thank you for your replies guys.
@Hans, I totally agree with you about classes' thread-safety responsibilities. The collection's owner object is responsible of thread-safe usage of it.

What about more abstract situation? How to write an unit test to check that some class can be safely used in multithread environment? I have never seen anything like that. Possibly you have seen or have done such things.

Comment: Clearly you have to test the client code's use of the class.  If you want to test if its possible at all to do so in a thread-safe way then write some and test that.  I can't think of any cases where that would be completely impossible so not so sure if you really proved anything worthwhile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mark btw, 'bad news' answers like this don't usually please.  Sounds to me you've got both feet firmly planted in reality, my compliments.

Comment: I think that all you said in reply to my initial question was a good answer. The more general problem of multithread class testing is a separate question which should be 'touched' by me before I will repost it on stackoverflow. (I just asked about some common practices.) So don't be be overmodest. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this falls into the category of *not your responsibility*. The `SyncRoot` property is there in case someone using your collection class wants to synchronize reads/writes, providing a convenient object to lock on—nothing more. (In fact the purpose of this property was widely misunderstood; the property itself is often regarded as rather useless, as [Hans has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775624/c-how-to-write-an-unit-test-for-thread-unsafe-collection/4775831#4775831).)

If you do feel you have sufficient reason to implement this interface, it is still the case that synchronization is entirely outside the scope of your type itself (as you have signaled by having the `IsSynchronized` property return `false`); as such it shouldn't really need to be unit tested on your end.

In fact, I believe it's quite common for implementors of the `ICollection` interface to simply ignore the `SyncRoot` property (set it to `null`). That should tell you something.

For a unit test, you could simply verify that the `SyncRoot` property is not `null`.